# Scale a floating table with a background image keeping 1:1 ratio

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to scale a table cell that has a background image for an email I'm developing. However, I'm having trouble making the height dynamic on the mobile version.

The table cell:

- Has no content over the background image
- Stacks on mobile
- Needs to show the image in a 1:1 ratio, with none of the image cut off at the top or the sides
- Is full width on mobile

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oph4ja5c/)**

The fiddle will make the issue clear when you resize your browser window - The cell stacks fine and the width is fine, it's the height that's the problem. The height of the cell is too low, cutting off some of the image.

I need the height to firstly be exactly 385px x 256px on desktop (the exact size of the image), then 100% width on mobile, while also having a full image height on mobile.

There are reasons behind this approach which are not worth boring you with here.

The code:

HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
     <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="215" height="256" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;" align="left" class="100p" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                <tr>
                    <td width="215" style="float:left;" align="left" class="displayproperlyplease 100nopad">

                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="256">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    TEXT
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="385" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="100p" style="float:left;display:inline" align="right">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20" ></td>
                    <td background="http://msgfocus.com/files/amf_to_infinity/workspace_83/2-years.jpg" style="background-position:left; background-size:cover; float:left;" bgcolor="#0c0807" width="385" class="100nopad" valign="right" align="middle">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="256">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                    <td width="20"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
    @media (max-width:630px) {
*[class="100p"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important; text-align:center !important;}
*[class="100pad"] {width:95% !important;}
*[class="100nopad"] {width:100% !important; padding-right: 0 !important; padding-left: 0 !important; float: none !important; text-align: center;}
*[class="displayproperlyplease 100nopad"] {width:100% !important; padding-right: 0 !important; padding-left: 0 !important; float: none !important; text-align: center;}
table[class="wrapper"] {width: 100%;}
table[class="wrapper"] .fl {width: 100% !important;float: left;height: auto;}
    }
```

How can I make the background image on mobile be 100% width, but have the height increase/reduce to ensure none of the image is cut off?

Comment: It would be easy if it didnt need to be a background image, but this is a requirement?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a background image

Comment: And it need to be fluid/hybrid and not just responsive, with fixed sizes?

Comment: Yes, fluid to be 100% width on any mobile device width